# global data pointer declaration in U-boot

Tags: u-boot

I am understanding the U-boot source with AM33xx config. 
While going through the source at https://git.ti.com/ti-u-boot/ti-u-boot/blobs/master/common/init/board_init.c#line126 , the malloc base was updated in the global data, but not sure where global data pointer(*gd) was defined.
Can you help to understand to know where global data pointer (*gd) was defined for Sitara processor.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it was defined in `arch/arm/include/asm/global_data.h` at `#define DECLARE_GLOBAL_DATA_PTR     register volatile gd_t *gd asm ("r9")` .
The DECLARE_GLOBAL_DATA_PTR macros used at the beginning of the file https://git.ti.com/ti-u-boot/ti-u-boot/blobs/master/common/init/board_init.c#line126 .